# Weak implicit function theorem. Is my proof alright?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that if we have $ f \in C(A \times U,Y)$, where $x_0 \in U$, $\lambda_0 \in A$ and A and U are open sets in Banach spaces and Y is a Banach space too and we have that: $f(\lambda_0,x_0)=0$ and $f_x(\lambda_0,x_0)$ is invertible and the inverse map is bounded and $f_x \in C(A \times U, L(U,Y))$, then we have that there is a continuous curve $x(\lambda)$ in a surrounding of $x_0$, such that $f(\lambda, x(\lambda))=0$

My idea was the following:

Look at $F(x,\lambda):= x - (f_x (\lambda_0,x_0))^{-1}f(\lambda,x)$ 
(The subscript x always denotes the partial derivative with respect to this coordinate).
Then we have: $F_x(x,\lambda):= \operatorname{id} - (f_x (\lambda_0,x_0))^{-1}f_x(\lambda,x)$

Therefore we have that $\| F(\lambda,x) - F(\lambda,x')\| \le \sup_{\xi} \| F_x(\lambda,\xi)\| \|x-x'\|$

Now we want to get a contraction by choosing $x \in B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ and $\lambda \in B_{\delta}(\lambda_0)$( notice that both balls shall be closed in order to apply Banach's fixed point theorem) such that: $$\|F_x(\lambda, x)\| =\| \operatorname{id} - (f_x (\lambda_0,x_0))^{-1}f_x(\lambda,x)\| \le \|f_x (\lambda_0,x_0))^{-1}\| \|f_x (\lambda_0,x_0) -f_x (\lambda,x))\| \le \|f_x (\lambda_0,x_0))^{-1}\|( \|f_x (\lambda_0,x_0) -f_x (\lambda,x_0))\| +  \|f_x (\lambda,x_0) -f_x (\lambda,x)\|) =: L < 1$$

This is possible since $f_x$ is continuous. Therefore, we have a contraction and we get by Banach's fixed point theorem a unique continuous function $x$ such that $x(\lambda) = F(\lambda,x(\lambda))$ for every lambda and since we know from $f(\lambda_0,x_0)=0$ that for $\lambda_0$ we have $F(\lambda_0,x(\lambda_0)) = x(\lambda_0)$, this function $x$ does what I want. Is this approach correct so far?

If something is unclear, please let me know. It is not unlikely that there is something wrong. I will also award the bounty if somebody has a good and helpful comment on this. If you think that everything is okay, then it is even better.

Comment: why $x$ is continuous?

Comment: This is supposed to follow from banach's fixed point theorem with parameters.

Comment: I didn't heard of parametrized version of this theorem, could you give a reference?

Comment: http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/techno/user_files/tse/nonlinpde.pdf

Comment: thank you! In this case I think your solution is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only slick moment in this correct proof is continuity of $x(\lambda)$. But this fact follows from [parametrized version of Banach fixed point theorem](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/techno/user_files/tse/nonlinpde.pdf) (proposition 1.5).